# installation without showing command prompt

Tags: windows-7, installation, cmd, installshield-2008

i have made a installer with installshield 2008 .

main problem is , while installation through setup.exe , command prompt appears several time in this procedure. for convenience of end user i need to remove command prompt during installation.

i read in previous threads i can call my batch file through a vbscript as a solution 
and i have tried to use vbscript in installshield 2008 instead of my batch file to run my batch file indirectoly through vbscript, it did not worked for me as a solution ..

please tell me , if i use vbscript to run my batch file then how can i include this vbsript in installshield

or , an

Comment: I think needs to use /silent flag or /s/v/qn flags for silent installation

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the VBS, but I don't believe it needs to be that complex.

All you need is a VBS file (let's call it `hide.vbs`). It contains `CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False`.

To activate it, put in the command `wscript.exe "hide.vbs" "file_path"` where `file_path` is the path to the batch file you want started.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why execute a batch script via a vbscript when you could do it better via a vbscript custom action? Doesn't make sense to me. Run the setup.exe silently by creating an answer file:

> setup.exe /r

Writes to response file 'C:\windows\setup.iss'.

> setup.exe /r /f1"C:\windows\temp\setup.iss"

Writes to file 'C:\windows\temp\setup.iss'
Then all you need to do is install the setup.exe silently:

> setup.exe /s /f1"C:\windows\temp\setup.iss"